# How Can I trigger a job inside a folder using Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin checking the state of the job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-scriptler

I am using Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin to trigger a job from remote server. I could trigger a job which is directly in the server.
My Questions :

1. How can I mention a job name which is inside a folder as TestFolder\TestJob ?
2. How Can I check the status (Success / Failure ) of the triggering job and trigger the remote job ?